# Retrieve Date based on Month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select a year value depending on the month the record was created:

If the month is January onwards, I should get last year
If the month is April onwards, I should get this year

```
SELECT IF ((MONTH(Application.created) > 3), (YEAR(Application.created)), (YEAR(Application.created, INTERVAL -1 YEAR))) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subtract 1 (no `interval` required) from the year value. Also, I used `CASE` because I was getting lost in all the parentheses :)

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN MONTH(Application.created) > 3 THEN YEAR(Application.created)
       ELSE YEAR(Application.created) - 1
  END
FROM Table
```

Edit:

```
SELECT IF ((MONTH(Application.created) > 3), (YEAR(Application.created)), (YEAR(Application.created) - 1)) FROM Table
```

Comment: I actually stuck to the `IF` statement but you gave me the idea of just subtracting `1`

Comment: No problem! And thanks - having the `IF` version improves the answer.